# get value from database if two rows exist and value is equal to

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to check is the value of a row exist on the database and if exist check the value of the second row, and if exist check the value of a third row. (quite bad redacted I think).

Three rows on a table called "notes" ['custom'], ['createdtime'] and ['status']

I need to check if ['custom'] exist on the database.

```
$notes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `notes` WHERE `custom` = '$custom'")
```

Then if $custom exist on the database I need to check if `['createdtime']` is less than 3 days old. `['createdtime']` has a value like 'Y-m-d H:i:s'

If that is ok (the value is less than 3 days old) i need to get the value of `['status']`

Any one can point to a suitable example of how to perform that check or similar.
I like to learn not to copy and paste, so any reference to a suitable example will be really appreciated, Examples or solutions are also welcome

Comment: Could you give a worked example showing what you are trying to do? It's hard to follow from your description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one query to do this, something like:

```
SELECT `status` FROM `notes` WHERE `custom` = '$custom' AND `createdTime` > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Full syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Comment: Shouldn't that be `createdTime > ...`?

Comment: i think createdTime and CURRENT_DATE may have different formats , so a conversion may be needed

Comment: Haa!, Thanks for the link and the example, I will accept your answer in two minutes. I'm just having a problem to echo the 'status' for some reason.

Comment: @CyprUS And doesn't less than 3 days old mean 2 days ago, 1 day ago, today and all days to come? If I'm reading that query correctly `(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY)` evaluates to a day 3 days ago and the condition is that `createdTime` should be a date before that, which would be more than 3 days old.

Comment: Flesk can you put an example showin what you mean ? or where according to you is and error with the 3 days ago validation ?

Comment: @user983248: `select current_date from dual where current_date < (current_date - interval 3 day);` - You'll agree that `current_date` (today) is less than 3 days old, and by Leonard's and CyprUs' logic that query should return a row. Yet it doesn't; for the exact reason I've expressed previously.

Comment: Yhea, but wait a second, The whole thing must give me the value of 'status' row if 'custom' exist and 'createdtime' is less than 3 days old (compared to today date), so yes you are right on that logic, but your example some how don't show how do you get there since ['status'] must be returned if all other rows are ok. Can you post an example as an answer not as a comment ? I will be glad to accept it as a valid answer is it is ok, Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Sorry about that - I've edited the answer, it now checks whether your date is **greater** than 3 days ago (i.e within the last 3 days). If it's still not working, feel free to add the table `create` statement.